# Caliburn.Micro BindableCollection is not updating in View code using code behind to set up bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, caliburn.micro, inotifypropertychanged

I want to create a WPF application using Caliburn.Micro MVVM. One of the Views should make a nice drawing of data obtained for the ViewModel. In the View, I want to do the drawing in code behind. I use scalar dependency properties. That works fine. I also can use data stored in a BindableCollection (LocationList in the example code below). What not works is updating the DependencyProperty if I add new elements to the BindableCollection. It must be a stupid mistake, but I do not see it. I created a demo application, leaving out as much as possible. It is a standard Caliburn.Micro setup. I do not show the Bootstrapper, ShellView and ShellViewModel here. They are the general starter configurations.

The ViewModel looks like this:

```
    using Caliburn.Micro;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace BindingCodeBehind.ViewModels
        {
        public class DemoViewModel : Screen
            {
            private BindableCollection<string> _locationList;
            public BindableCollection<string> LocationList
                {
                get { return _locationList; }
                set
                    {
                    _locationList = value; 
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>LocationList);
                    }
                }

            public DemoViewModel()
                {
                LocationList = new BindableCollection<string>();
                }

            protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
                {
                base.OnViewLoaded(view);
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                    // BindableCollection supports AddRange, but not Add. 
                    LocationList.AddRange( new List<string>{$"Test nr {i}"});
                    // LocationList.Add($"Test nr {i}");
                    }
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>LocationList.Count);
                }
            }
        }
```

`LocationList` is initialized in the constructor. I add data in the `OnViewLoaded` event handler.

The XAML code of the View is nothing special, just a scaffolded `UserControl`, nothing added. The code behind looks like this:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace BindingCodeBehind.Views
    {
    public partial class DemoView : UserControl
        {
        public BindableCollection<string> LocationList
            {
            get { return (BindableCollection<string>) GetValue(LocationListProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LocationListProperty, value);}
            }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LocationListProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LocationList", 
                typeof(BindableCollection<string>), 
                typeof(DemoView),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, 
                                            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                                            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnLocationListChanged)));

        public DemoView()
            {
            InitializeComponent();
            var myBinding = new Binding
                {
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                Path = new PropertyPath("LocationList"),
                NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true
                };
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, LocationListProperty, myBinding);
            }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
            {
            // Data from LocationLst should be used in drawing 
            }

        private static void OnLocationListChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
            // I assume this called if LocationList changes
            }
        }
    }
```

In the code a dependency property `LocationList` is created. In the constructor I created a binding for this property. In the debugger, I ca see this actually works. `OnLocationListChanged` should be invoked if this list changes. I see this is called when I create the `LocationList` in the constructor of the ViewModel, but the handle is not called again, when I add three elements to the `LocationList`. Therefore, I think the issue is somewhere in the handling of `INotifyChange`. To get a better understanding, I looked up the source code of the `BindableCollection` class and saw the `Add` method is not implemented, so I changed in the ViewModel my code to use the `AddRange` method, just to be sure but it does not help.

I tried a lot of things, but I am completely out of ideas on how to get this working. I really hope someone can help me out. Basically, all this should cause my application the call `OnRender` again to update the drawing. This is my first WPF drawing application and my first Caliburn.Micro application, so this all is still new for me.

My development environment: Visual Studio 2019, community edition, .Net Core 3.1 C# 8.0, Windows10. All updated with the latest patches.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that "*OnLocationListChanged should be invoked if this list changes*" is wrong.

A callback of a dependency property is only called when the property itself is set to a new value, i.e. when you assign it to a new instance of a `BindableCollection<string>`.

It's doesn't get invoked when you add items to or remove items from the collection. There is a `CollectionChanged` event that you can handle to in response to individual items getting added or removed.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. It does not yet solve my problem, because I no not (yet) know how to implement the CollectionChanged event in View. The BindableCollection invokes this event, so no issue on that side. For PropertyChanged DepencyProperty.Register helps, but not for CollectionChanged. I can register to the event, that works, but it seems not to invoked. I will see how Microsoft does this in the generated XAML code. I found sample code for a Window, but not for a UserControl. Any ideas or sample code is welcome

Comment: @RudolfJan: You could hook up an event handler to the event in the `OnLocationListChanged` callback.